# Stop html table cell breaking on minus sign and instead on decimal point?

Tags: html, html-table

Is it possible to stop a TD breaking on the minus sign of a value and instead make it break on the decimal point?

I have a table displaying decimal amounts from a database.  Some of the amounts are large and need to wrap somehow.

At the moment, when a value exceeds my TD's width it get truncated as follows:

```
-
123456.00
```

But Is there any way to make it break as:

```
-12345
.00
```

without having to manually intervene and format the strings?  i.e. can it be done in css or another way?

**EDIT**

Both of these work in Firefox, but not in IE8 (second and third columns are

```
<td>
 -1234567&#8203;.89
</td>
<td>
 -1234567<wbr>.89
</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `<wbr>` tag like so:

```
-123456<wbr>.00
```

To make it more browser compatible you can use this too: ([ref](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html))

```
&#8203;
```

Comment: This sounds like what I need...but can't get it to work in VS2010 and MVC3/Razor :(

Comment: Tried both <wbr> and 8203 but still get the same layout: minus sign on first line, remaining figure on the second line.  It just means users reading the screen sometimes miss the "-".

Comment: Try <TD nowrap="nowrap">-123456<wbr>.00</td>

Comment: Some websites are saying that the tag is new to HTML5, if so it will only work in newer browsers. I always thought it was around before HTML5 though...

Comment: Would have thought this was an important tag for positioning and readability - I'd want WBR suggestions so when I changed font sizes the site remained the same...tables can be a PITA at the best of times!  Thanks @Jleagle

Answer (score 2):

`<TD NOWRAP>` stops all linefeeds maybe what you search for?

**Edit:** And manualy linefeeds with `<br>`!